# yum Package Install on RHEL reports "This system is not registered with an entitlement server"

Tags: rhel, yum

I downloaded Red Hat Enterprise Linux today, and when I try to install a package using yum, I get:

```
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# yum install openssh
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Nothing to do
```

What do I do?

Comment: Did you purchase a Redhat subscription?

Answer (score 10):

If you signed up to the no-cost developer license or have an actual license with Redhat, then you need to subscribe the server to RHN, using the `subscription-manager` command.

Use this command to register, using the credentials you use to access access.redhat.com.

`subscription-manager register --username <username> --password <password> --auto-attach`

Comment: This is probably the right answer for me, but it complains about a self signed certificate when I try to register.

Comment: I actually had to change my Virtualbox machine to use a bridged adapter, and that was enough to register.

Answer (score 6):

While Redhat fully adheres and is a big contributor to many open-source projects, its business model requires its customers to buy a license in order to use its products and services.

The usual alternative if you don't intend to pay money for the license, is to use its clone, built from the very same sources [RHEL](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/linux-platforms/enterprise-linux) is built upon: [CentOS](https://www.centos.org/). Almost everything will be the same, except mostly two things: license management tools, and security fixes tag informations (ie, it's difficult to know if an upgrade is a security fix or not, but the upgrade will exist nonetheless).

So you should consider reinstalling from a [CentOS installation image](https://www.centos.org/download/) instead.

Comment: It's possible that the asker actually has licenses, but doesn't know how to register their system properly.

Comment: @Centimane  if that's the case, I'll delete my answer. I considered this was unlikely

Comment: @A.B will the packages be the same?

Comment: They are recompiled from the same sources. But they won't be byte-for-byte the same. A checksum on them or their content will be different.